# Defective wires - probability

Tags: probability

Wire cable used to secure bridge structure has an average of three defects per $100$ yards. If you require $50$ yards, what is the probability that there will be one defect and at least two defects

Comment: This question can't be answered with just what you've told us.

Comment: I believe it can. Consider this as a Poisson process with rate $\lambda = 3/100$...

Comment: @user38584 We don't know how the defects are distributed.

Comment: Fair enough, but that is the assumption I would make unless otherwise specified.

Answer (score 1):

This question can't be answered with only what you've told us. The reason is that we don't know how the defects are distributed; what kind of randomness (if they are random) do the defects follow?

---

To demonstrate this, I'll give two examples of situations that are consistent with what you've told us, but give different answers to your question.

Suppose the reason there's an average of three defects per $100$ yards is that there is *always* a defect at every $100/3$-yard mark. Then the probability that there's at least one defect in a randomly chosen $50$-yard wire is $1$.

Now suppose instead that every $10$-yard segment of wire independently has a $30\%$ chance of having a defect. Then the probability that there's at least one defect in a randomly chosen $50$-yard wire is $$1-\left(\frac{7}{10}\right)^5 \neq 1$$

Comment: Thanks for adding the examples.